# Is there any Eclipse API to parse CSS and HTML?

Tags: java, html, css, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree

Eclipse provide very nice aproach to build AST tree from [PHP](http://eclipsesourcecode.appspot.com/jsrcs/org.eclipse.pdt/plugins/org.eclipse.php.core/src/org/eclipse/php/internal/core/ast/nodes/ASTParser.java.html), [JavaScript](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.doc/reference/api/org/eclipse/wst/jsdt/core/dom/ASTParser.html) and [JAVA](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.jsdt.doc%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fwst%2Fjsdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FASTParser.html) code. You can go over every each element of language recieving positions of that elements + it validate code and you have positions of syntax errors.

I tried to find similiar API for HTML and CSS but without successes. I'm sure that it exist, because Eclipse support highlighting and code assist for that languages. Will be happy to receive any advice!

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the WebTools source editing project?
http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/webtools.sourceediting

They offer editors for CSS and HTML. The Validators are alo part of this prpject I think.
As HTML and CSS is different from programming languages, you may not get an AST similar to Java, adn the derived PHP and Javascript plugins.

Your question maybe easier to answer when you state why you need access to the AST: erro checking, automated code refactoring, ...

If you cannot find it in those projects, you can have a look at ANTLR, where you create you own language definitions, compile them to Java. These are then quite easy to put into an Eclipse Builder, so you can have access to the AST you created for the files you're editing.

Comment: Yep, I saw that, but I didn't find any documentation or examples for this. I don't know where to start. I need it and for error checking and for code refactoring and for code highliting. In fact Im writing IDE for android.

Comment: WebTools has validators and editors already, so what makes them unsuitable? Have you looked at Aptana [link](http://www.aptana.com)?

Comment: I think it's suitable, but I can't find any documentation or examples how to get started with this API. In fact Im not sure that this part of a WTP can be used outside Eclipse, maybe it contains a lot of hard-coded dependencies with UI modules. And I don't understand how Aptana can help me in my purpose?

Comment: If you want to make an IDE for Android I presumed you want to make an eclipse based IDE, is that correct?, if not how do you expect to consume Eclipse-originated code.

Comment: No, not eclipse based. I want just use some modules like org.eclipse.php.core, org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Eclipse for Java EE is what you want. It validates HTML code, I'm not sure about CSS

Comment: You didn't understand my question. I'm writing my own IDE for Android that uses Eclipse libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I use eclipse for php. This distribuition does edit html, css, javascript files : http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/heliosr

Comment: Could you provide a little bit more information, something like code snippet or full class name that you used for those purposes?

Answer (score 0):

[JSOUP](https://jsoup.org/) is a simple HTML/CSS parser

For CSS alone you could try the [GWT CSS abstraction](https://vaadin.com/api/7.6.6/com/google/gwt/resources/css/GenerateCssAst.html)